# remove the "powered by spree" footer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I'm looking to remove the "powered by spree" footer. does anyone know 
where this is located?

also, how is the "Shop By" overridden when adding a new taxonomy?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer**: These tips may not work exactly as written in latest versions of Spree. I have not worked with Spree recently.

For Spree version 1.0, you can override **app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb**. I think the path is slightly different in the current version from previous (pre- 1.0) versions.

As a cleaner option, you can use Deface to remove the "Powered by Spree" statement in the footer like so:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/layouts/spree_application",
                 :name => "footer-left",
                 :remove => "#footer-left")
```

If you want to replace it instead, you can do something like:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/layouts/spree_application", 
                 :name => "footer-left",
                 :replace_contents => "#footer-left", 
                 :text => "My Left Footer Text")
```

Or even niftier:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/layouts/spree_application",
                 :name => "footer-left",
                 :replace_contents => "#footer-left") do
 '<div id="footer-left" class="columns alpha eight" data-hook>
    <p><%= t(:powered_by) %> <%= link_to "YuriTek", "http://yuritek.com" %></p>
 </div>'
end
```

Just put the statement above into an rb file and place it in the app/overrides directory. I think putting it into config/initializers would work too.

P.S. Deface is included in Spree out of the box.

Comment: OK, this actually works fine for me. Would appreciate a comment for why it's down-voted.

Comment: didnt work for me. using spree 1.2. I had to override the footer partial.

Comment: OK, it's been a while since I've worked with Spree, so I have added a version disclaimer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This updates both Binary and yuri's answers for **Spree v1.3**

the footer has moved into the partial `app/views/spree/shared/_footer.html.erb`

so to override it using Deface you can either of these two methods:

1. Deface::Override - this is the traditional method (as per yuri's answer)
2. the Deface DSL - .deface files (as per Binary's answer)

So to use Deface::Override, create a file `app/overrides/remove_footer.rb` containing:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/shared/_footer',
         :name => 'remove_footer',
         :remove => '#footer[data-hook]'
        )
```

**OR**
to use the Deface DSL, create a file `app/overrides/spree/shared/footer/remove_footer.deface` containing:

```
remove '#footer[data-hook]'
```

see the documentation at https://github.com/spree/deface for more information, it is good.

Answer (score 1):

Yuri's answer is fine but I like the Deface DSL syntax better.  For Spree 1.0 or above, create a file called `remove_powered_by.deface` in the directory `app/overrides/spree/layouts/spree_application/` and add the following contents:

```
<!--
  remove '#footer-left > p:first-child'
-->
```

That's it.

You can see numerous examples of overrides in my company's Spree store code at 
https://github.com/binaryphile/spree_dibs_1.3